# Using only integers to get 2 decimals of division

Tags: c

How do I only use integer to get 2 decimals for integer division? No casting or other variables, functions, no.

The function is, int fraction(int numerator, int denominator). Numerator can be big than denominator

I tried this but can't work. First I try simplify the numerator and then multiply by 1000 but its not work for some fractions. Then I try imitate to real life doing division but its lots of bugs too. Can I have some help?

Comment: Share some code that you have written.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and post an [mcve].

Comment: If you show us the long division attempt we can help debug it. We need code to go off of, a vague description means that we'd be giving a vague answer, or doing a disproportionate amount of work to give you a full answer.

Comment: Provide a sample input and desired output for your prgogram.

Answer (score 1):

I would scale the integer (multiply by 100)

```
long long divxy(long long x, long long y)
{
    x *= 100;
    x /= y;
    return x;
}

void print(long long x)
{
    long long temp = x / 100;
    printf("%s%lld.%02d\n", (temp == 0 && x < 0) ? "-" : "", temp, abs(x % 100));
}

int main(void)
{
    long long result;

    result = divxy(1,3);
    print(result);
    result = divxy(-2,3);
    print(result);
    result = divxy(-200,3);
    print(result);
    result = divxy(176789,-456);
    print(result);
}
```

or with correct rounding

```
long long divxy(long long x, long long y)
{
    x *= 1000;
    x /= y;
    if(abs(x % 10) > 5) x += 10 * (x < 0 ? -1 : 1);
    x /= 10;
    return x;
}
```

or version which will not overflow (except some theoretical (and probably non existing) C implementations where LLONG_MAX < INT_MAX * 1000)

```
long long divxy(int x, int y)
{
    long long xl = (long long)x * 1000;
    xl /= y;
    if(abs(xl % 10) > 5) xl += 10 * (xl < 0 ? -1 : 1);
    xl /= 10;
    return xl;
}
```

Comment: Could an overflow occur - `LLONG_MAX * 100`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil forgoten format.

Comment: it can of course you can add sanitization yourself

Comment: @EricPostpischil `long long. It can also be not much narrower` on the PC computers it will not. So it simple impractical nitpick.  (same most uCs). I do not know any modern C implementations where long long is not significantly different from the int. Do you know any?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Amended the answer to express your concerns

Comment: I voted up. And after all that work, somebody voted down.

Comment: @EricPostpischil it is normal :)